# TikZ — Dot fillers in text nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to redraw a simple A2 poster created in InDesign with TikZ and I need some dot fillers for some kind of a "table of contents":

[image]

The `\dotfill` does nothing (well, there are no "lines").

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}           
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{25mm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
        \clip[] (-2, 2) rectangle (452, -302);

        %\node[anchor=north] at (226, -5) {\includegraphics[height=90mm]{logo}};
        \draw[] (0, 0) rectangle (450, -300);

        \node[anchor=west, font=\fontsize{33}{35}\selectfont] at (30, -110) {A \dotfill 1};
        \node[anchor=west, font=\fontsize{33}{35}\selectfont] at (30, -128) {Abc \dotfill 10};
        \node[anchor=west, font=\fontsize{33}{35}\selectfont] at (30, -146) {Abcd \dotfill 100};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to avoid manual adjustment of dots between letters and numbers?

Comment: `dotfill` will stretch to fill the required space, but in your nodes there's no space to fill.  Did you try: `\makebox[2in]{A \dotfill 1}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the nodes some width to be filled by dots

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[a2paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{noto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}           
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{25mm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=1mm, y=1mm]
        \clip[] (-2, 2) rectangle (452, -302);

        %\node[anchor=north] at (226, -5) {\includegraphics[height=90mm]{logo}};
        \draw[] (0, 0) rectangle (450, -300);

        \node[anchor=west, text width=300mm, font=\fontsize{33}{35}\selectfont] at (30, -110) {A \dotfill 1};
        \node[anchor=west, text width=300mm, font=\fontsize{33}{35}\selectfont] at (30, -128) {Abc \dotfill 10};
        \node[anchor=west, text width=300mm, font=\fontsize{33}{35}\selectfont] at (30, -146) {Abcd \dotfill 100};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works well (like the Thurston's `\makebox`) thank you!